# Is it possible to programmatically change the XDR Display Reference Mode (aka Preset) on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, automator, apple-developer

Apple's XDR Displays like the Pro Display XDR and the Liquid Retina Display XDR support Display Reference Modes, also known as Presets. These can be changed from within System Preferences > Displays > Display Settings > Presets (After selecting an XDR Display).

Is there a way to get the list of available Presets and change the current Preset programmatically? Whether it's through a script or through an API? It seems like ColorSync is used to change/set a color profile but I don't see any reference for setting a preset within ColorSync.

Documentation for Reference Modes:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210435

Comment: As I have neither a **MacBook Pro** with **Liquid Retina XDR** display or **Apple Pro Display XDR**, I cannot say much other than to say if I had one or the other I certainly could use **AppleScript** and **UI Scripting** to make changes as shown in the images in the linked documentation in your question. As to whether or not it can be accomplished in another manner I can't say, sorry.

Comment: @user3439894, Oh wow that would certainly be an option to do this. I hadn't considered UI Scripting. I'll be sure to give that a try for now until I can find a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done by compiling against the private `MonitorPanel.framework` which is what System Settings uses to change resolutions and presets.

Here is [a simple Swift file](https://github.com/alin23/mac-utils/blob/063c2072bb86840584d74d579016106288e2034b/ReferencePreset.swift) that can list and change presets along with the [required headers](https://github.com/phatblat/macOSPrivateFrameworks/tree/9047371eb80f925642c8a7c4f1e00095aec66044/PrivateFrameworks/MonitorPanel) to compile it. *I also provide a [compiled binary](https://github.com/alin23/mac-utils#referencepreset) and [Apple Shortcuts support in lunar.fyi](https://lunar.fyi/shortcuts#graphic-work-preset) for convenience.*

And here's some sample code to list displays with their active preset, then activating the **"Design & Print (P3-D50)"** preset for the first display.

*presets.swift*

```swift
guard let mgr = MPDisplayMgr(), let display = mgr.displays.first(where: \.hasPresets) else {
    exit(1)
}

print("\(display.displayName!): \"\(display.activePreset!.presetName!)\"")

if let preset = display.presets.first(where: { $0.presetName == "Design & Print (P3-D50)" }) {
    print("Activating preset \"Design & Print (P3-D50)\" for \(display.displayName!)")
    display.setActivePreset(preset)
}
```

*Bridging-Header.h*

```c
#import <MonitorPanel/MPDisplayPreset.h>
#import <MonitorPanel/MPDisplay.h>
#import <MonitorPanel/MPDisplayMgr.h>
#import <MonitorPanel/MPDisplayMode.h>
```

Compiler command:

```bash
swiftc -F$PWD/Headers \
    -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks \
    -framework MonitorPanel \
    -import-objc-header Bridging-Header.h \
    presets.swift -o presets
./presets
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already succeeded another way you could start from these Applescript lines:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.2
    click button "Displays" of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell
```

Once you have done so (hopefully successful) move your cursor to the next button or pop-up-button, press Cmd-Shift-4 and:
 take a note of coordinates ([X], [Y]).
 put these into a new script `tell application "System Events" to click at {[X], [Y]}`.
   *This script will in its "results" part show a definition of this (pop-up-) button (must be visible).*
 append the definition after the first "click"-line (above) supplemented by `click` at the beginning (minus: `of application "System Events"`) plus `delay`.
 Repeat these steps for every "level" of selections you need for your goal.
*(I suggest you test the script after every appendix…)*